# How to order twice in the same query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How do you order something twice in the same query? For example I can order search for the top ten tagged courses by

```
categories = Category.all.limit(10).order(tags_count: :desc)
```

I can also order them alphabetically by

```
categories = Category.all.order(title: :desc)
```

How do you order by title *after* the top ten tagged courses have been queried? I tried this but it didn't work

```
categories = Category.all.limit(10).order(tags_count: :desc).order(title: :desc)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't work"?

Comment: We're trying to order the entire set of results returned from `Category.all.limit(10).order(tags_count: :desc)` by `title`. What I tried only orders categories with the same tags_count by title

Comment: It seems to me that's how `order` works. Try this `Category.where(id: Category.order(tags_count: :desc).limit(10)).order(title: :desc)`.

Comment: @Sabastian, can you explain the need of Subquery here? I see other 2 answers should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @SebastianPalma that worked. thank you

Comment: You can answer your own question @vince, the problem is you need "another way" to sort your records, and the query given relies on a combination of `IN` and `ORDER BY` to ensure the order of the resulting rows.

Comment: I think I mostly understand the query and I'm assuming this is more efficient than sorting alphabetically in Ruby. Thank you @SebastianPalma -- I was waiting to give you credit but I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 2):

You may try ordering by a raw SQL expression:

```
categories = Category.all.limit(10).order('tags_count desc, title desc')
```

Comment: You don't need to add `all` in `Category.all` Active record will pick it up automatically even if you don't mention it when using `limit` or `order`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this -

```
Category.order(tags_count: :desc, title: :desc).limit(10)
```

What this will do is that it will first sort based on the `tags_count` in `descending` order and then sort the sorted result set on `title` in `descending` order.Then take the first `10` results and return those.

Comment: There's no difference between `Model.limit(...).order(...)` and `Model.order(...).limit(...)`, neither between `Model.order(...).order(...)` and `Model.order(..., ...)`,  the SQL generated always places the LIMIT clause at the end of the statement and `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#order` are chainable, so it's like the same.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yup, I am aware of that. But my answer tries to achieve 2 things - 
1) Tell a better way to write the same query
2) Explain why it might not be working as the OP wants because of the 2nd sorting happening on the already sorted set.

Comment: This doesn't return the results in alphabetical order. I believe it orders categories with the same tags_count alphabetically. We need to order the entire results from Category.all.limit(10).order(tags_count: :desc) alphabetically by title

Comment: Yes, that's what it will do. What you are saying seems a little odd, if you have already ordered by the tag count, and then you want the whole set again to be ordered alphabetically by title then the previous order of tag count wouldn't stay.

Comment: I'm not great with sql but what we need is the top ten tagged categories sorted alphabetically. I guess I could sort them using Ruby but I was hoping I didn't have to

Comment: top ten tagged categories sorted alphabetically means - Sorting categories as top 10 based on their tag count and then those categories will be sorted alphabetically, which is what my answer achieves.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that worked for me. Thank you @SebastianPalma for your help!

```
Category.where(id: Category.order(tags_count: :desc).limit(10)).order(title: :desc)
```